# Git Copy files to a server

Tags: git

In git I have a bitbucket remote setup and in local I have a new folder withfiles. How can I pull all the files in the remote to my local without deleting the files that arn't in the remote

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1:** These are un-tracked file
You can just `pull`. None of your un-tracked files will be replaced

Git is a version control system. It keeps track of files you've asked it to track. So if you haven't set a file for git tracking it won't be replaced even if you `git pull` from remote.

Here's a demo bash script that will actually recreate your scenario.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#from your home (~/) directory 
mkdir temp && cd temp

#Init a git bare repo (this is your remote)
git init --bare remote.git

#create local working tree 1 (this is user 1)
mkdir local_1 && cd local_1
git init
git remote add origin ~/temp/remote.git
touch file1
git add file1
git commit -m "first commit"
git push --set-upstream origin master
cd ..

# create local working tree 2 (this is user 2)
git clone remote.git
mv remote local_2 && cd local_2
touch file2

#make a new commit in local_1 and push it
cd ../local_1
touch file3
git add file3
git commit -m "second commit"
git push

#come back to local_2
cd ../local_2
#Pull and update your branch
git pull
#let's see if you still have file2 in your working tree.
ls file2
#yes you do!
```

After running this you can find that `file2` still exist in your `local_2` directory.

**Scenario 2**: These are tracked file.
A pull will result in a conflict if the files have changed. So you just have to do the work to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

I almost never use `git pull` and instead always use `git fetch <remote>` (such as `git fetch origin`). This fetches the files from your remote without modifying your local working files. You can then inspect further by doing something like:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph -20
```

I actually have that aliased as `git tree` - you can set up the alias using:

```
git config alias.tree llog --decorate --oneline --graph -20'
```

Once you fetch the files using `git fetch <remote>` you'll be able to look at them using the `git tree` alias I provided or by checking out a remote branch.